# Can't change _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL property

Tags: python, x11, xcb, ewmh

I want to reserve some space on the screen for my Gtk application written in Python. I've wrote this function:

```
import xcb, xcb.xproto
import struct
def reserve_space(xid, data):
    connection = xcb.connect()
    atom_cookie = connection.core.InternAtom(True, len("_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL"), 
        "_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL")
    type_cookie = connection.core.InternAtom(True, len("CARDINAL"), "CARDINAL")
    atom = atom_cookie.reply().atom
    atom_type = type_cookie.reply().atom
    data_p = struct.pack("I I I I I I I I I I I I", *data)
    strat_cookie = connection.core.ChangeProperty(xcb.xproto.PropMode.Replace, xid,
        atom, xcb.xproto.Atom.CARDINAL, 32, len(data_p), data_p)
    connection.flush()
```

It's call looks like this:

```
utils.reserve_space(xid, [0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 767, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Where is an error in my code?

UPD:
[Here](http://pastebin.com/tawxjPfE) is my xprop output. My WM is Compiz.

Comment: Can you print `xprop -id [xid here]` before and after call? What window manager are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to using ChangePropertyChecked(), and then checking the result gives a BadLength exception.

I think the bug here is that the `ChangeProperty()` parameter `data_len` is the number of elements of the size given by `format` , not the number of bytes, in the property data `data`.

Slightly modified code which works for me:

```
def reserve_space(xid, data):
    connection = xcb.connect()
    atom_cookie = connection.core.InternAtom(False, len("_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL"),
        "_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL")
    atom = atom_cookie.reply().atom
    data_p = struct.pack("12I", *data)
    strat_cookie = connection.core.ChangePropertyChecked(xcb.xproto.PropMode.Replace, xid,
        atom, xcb.xproto.Atom.CARDINAL, 32, len(data_p)/4, data_p)
    strat_cookie.check()
    connection.flush()
```

Comment: Note that using only_if_exists=FALSE for the InternAtom is probably a good idea, so this works as expected if this client is started before the WM (or any other client which interns "_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL")

Answer (score 2):

I have uploaded a [gist](https://gist.github.com/johnlane/351adff97df196add08a) that demonstrates how to specify a strut across the top of the current monitor for what might be a task-bar. It may help explain some of this.

The gist of my gist is below:

```
 window = gtk.Window()
 window.show_all()
 topw = window.get_toplevel().window
 topw.property_change("_NET_WM_STRUT","CARDINAL",32,gtk.gdk.PROP_MODE_REPLACE,
      [0, 0, bar_size, 0])
 topw.property_change("_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL","CARDINAL",32,gtk.gdk.PROP_MODE_REPLACE,
      [0, 0, bar_size, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, x+width, 0, 0])
```

I found the strut arguments confusing at first, so here is an explanation that I hope is clearer:

we set `_NET_WM_STRUT`, the older mechanism as well as `_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL` but window managers ignore the former if they support the latter. The numbers in the array are as follows:

- `0, 0, bar_size, 0` are the number of pixels to reserve along each edge of the screen given in the order *left*, *right*, *top*, *bottom*. Here the size of the bar is reserved at the top of the screen and the other edges are left alone.
- `_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL` also supplies a further four pairs, each being a start and end position for the strut (they don't need to occupy the entire edge).

In the example, we set the top start to the current monitor's x co-ordinate and the top-end to the same value plus that monitor's width. The net result is that space is reserved only on the current monitor.

Note that co-ordinates are specified relative to the screen (i.e. all monitors together).

(see the referenced gist for the full context)